# MongoDB using $project to get from an array elements by key

Tags: database, mongodb

I have the following documents in a collection

```
{
  _id:"1",
  address: "My office",
  email:"xxx@yyy.com",
  trxs:[
     {
       type: 'sale',
       amount: 800
     },
     {
       type: 'buy',
       amount: 300
     }
  ]
},
{
  _id:"2",
  address: "My house",
  email:"zzz@www.com",
  trxs:[
     {
       type: 'buy',
       amount: 200
     },
     {
       type: 'sale',
       amount: 400
     }
  ]
},
```

I want to use `$project` to get the documents as follow:

```
{
  email:"xxx@yyy.com",
  sale: 800,
  buy: 300
},
{
  email: "zzz@www.com",
  buy: 200,
  sale: 400
}
```

I can't use `$arrayElementAt` because the array is randomized and the sale can be at position 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can unwind "trxs" field and then use $group and $cond to add value of sale object to sale field and buy object to buy field.

Following aggregation can be a solution to your problem:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$trxs" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      email: { $last: "$email" },
      sale: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$trxs.type", "sale"] }, "$trxs.amount", 0] },
      },
      buy: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$trxs.type", "buy"] }, "$trxs.amount", 0] },
      },
    },
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } },
]);
```

Comment: The $unwind method works, but performance wise is really slow. Actually is faster to implement the behavior by code, but I believe that is not a correct approach as it must be better the DB makes all the work. Any way to improve it?